# Router Link only updates active class once

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use `<b-nav-item>` tags as router links but the active link class only updates one time – I can load the page and click on a nav item and the class changes appropriately. But clicking again does not.

I have tried various syntax for the link attributes including:

```html
to="dashboard"
to="/dashboard"
:to="{ name: 'Dashboard' }"
:to="{ path: '/dashboard' }"
```

I've also tried adding the `exact` attribute tag. Nothing is working and I feel like I'm running in circles here. Any ideas?

CompanionNavigation:

```html
<template>
<div>
  <b-nav pills>
      <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'Dashboard'}" exact>Dashboard</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'Contacts' }" exact>Contacts</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</div>
</template>
```

Routes:

```
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
},
{
    path: '/contacts',
    name: 'Contacts',
    component: Contacts,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by removing the following from my main template file:

```html
<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
```